# Trouble displaying hourly data from a multi-dimensional array in d3js

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to display a multi-line chart of temperatures for 5 days on an hourly basis. I was able to create the both axes but I'm having trouble displaying the lines. 
I have a JSON like so where x is a date object for every 3 hours and y is the temperature.

```
var dataset = [
//day 1
[
{x: Date 2015-09-07T21:00:00.000Z, y: 30.75},
{x: Date 2015-09-08T00:00:00.000Z, y: 29.32},
{x: Date 2015-09-08T03:00:00.000Z, y: 25.67},
{x: Date 2015-09-08T06:00:00.000Z, y: 22.7}
],
//day 2
[
{x: Date 2015-09-08T09:00:00.000Z, y: 23.69},
{x: Date 2015-09-08T12:00:00.000Z, y: 24.18},
{x: Date 2015-09-08T15:00:00.000Z, y: 26.69},
{x: Date 2015-09-08T18:00:00.000Z, y: 22.36},
{x: Date 2015-09-08T21:00:00.000Z, y: 23.91},
{x: Date 2015-09-09T00:00:00.000Z, y: 22.98}
],
//day 3
Array[8],
//day 4
Array[8],
//day 5
Array[8]
]
```

When initialize the graph like below, instead of a multi-line graph, I get one line containing all 4 days.

```
var chart = lineChart("graph")
        .x(d3.time.scale().domain([
            dataset[0][0].x, dataset[3][7].x
        ]))
        .y(d3.scale.linear().domain([min, max]));
dataset.forEach(function (series) {
    chart.addSeries(series);
});

chart.render();
```

If I change the domain to,

```
dataset[4][0].x, dataset[4][7].x
```

it only draws the line for that day.

The strange thing is that when I "Inspect Elemet" via the browser, I can see that all 5 paths have been drawn out but they just dont show up on the UI. I think this has something to do with the way I'm setting the domain but I'm not sure what.

How do I set the domain so that d3js plots each days array on a 24-hour x-axis?

Comment: Can you give us visibility to the rest of the code or perhaps a jsfiddle? That will help a bunch to debug.

Comment: Here is a JSFiddle containing the code: http://jsfiddle.net/Q5Jag/1266/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to have the x-axis from midnight to midnight, as if everything is happening "on one day", like so:

[image]

**NOTE**: something is a bit weird with the timestamps in the source. I have no idea how `dt` and `dt_text` are related. Please adjust my examples accordingly...

How can you get that?

The problem in your code is indeed related to the `domain`. How?

If you set the domain to be from the very first timestamp to the last, like:

```
.domain([
        dataset[0][0].x, dataset[3][7].x
    ])
```

then the chart will span over 4 days (by the way: these hard-coded indices are not very robust coding...)

So the chart will then obviously plot over all days, it has no way of knowing that you only want hourly time-stamps.

If you, on the other hand, just use the most recent day as domain:

.domain([
            dataset[3][0].x, dataset[3][7].x
        ]))

It will plot just that, i.e. the last day. The other lines will be plotted too (what you see in the inspector), but the will be hidden away on the left (as you clip the stuff).

So: the problem is, that the x-coordinates **are** different, as they occur on different dates. There is plenty of ways to work around that (I personally always use moment.js for dates), but to show the effect, here's a quick hack to achieve the graph above:

[-> JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chroth/o416nwuu/3/)

What did I do? I added a new helper function to calculate the x time-stamp:

```
function gDate2(date) {
  var now = new Date();
  var hours = (new Date(date * 1000)).getHours();
  var date = now.getDate();
  var month = now.getMonth();
  var d = new Date(2015, month, date, hours, 0, 0, 0);
  return d;
}
```

Yes, it's not pretty. Personally, I like moment.js to calculate dates and stuff. The important part is that I return all dates as if it's all today (or any other arbitrary day). Then I extract the hour of the timestamp of the according data point and add that (as in the note: maybe you need minutes, seconds too?)

If you are going to use it, please make sure you have timezones, day-light saving etc. under control! I hate dates...)

And again: I am not sure about `dt` and `dt_text`. Make sure you got that right!

I hope this helps.